# Syntax error: Expected "(" or keyword UNNEST but got identifier "t" [at 10:56] ..SUBSTRING(t.user.email, 1, POSITION('@' IN t.user.email) - 1) as ldap

Tags: sql, syntax-error

```
SELECT 
    sub.ldap,
    t.status_update_time_millis,
    v.bitrix_lead,
    v.current_shift
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            t.user.email,
            SUBSTRING(t.user.email, 1, POSITION('@' IN t.user.email) - 1) as ldap
        FROM 
            Table1 AS t
        WHERE 
            t.vendor IN ('ICO_BS')
            AND t.status IN ('ACTIVE')
    ) AS sub
JOIN 
    Table2 AS v ON sub.ldap = v.ldap
```

**1. I want to split the contents of the column email in Table 1 and save it in ldap,
2. ldap would be used to join Table1 and Table2

**

Comment: Add a tag for the dbms you're using. (Some non-standard above.)

Comment: `t.user.email` means **table t**, **column user** and **method email**. Is that as intended?

Comment: `user` is a reserved word, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SQL_reserved_words. I.e. needs to be delimited as `"user"` (or choose another, non-reserved, name.)